# Get the text value of cell that is being edited UITableView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, edit

I have a UITableView, that is editable.

When the user deletes the cell, I want to get the text value of the cell, and remove it from a dictionary (which I can do).

However, I don't know how to get the cells value text. Also, is there another way that is similar to the html5 `data-xxx` that I can read and access?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
...
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *cellText = cell.textLabel.text;
/* you may need cell.detailTextLabel.text too */
...
```

In general, I'd say it's easier to track the content with the `indexPath` and use the row index to access your dictionary or array in order to remove the deleted cell content.

Comment: thats good, thanks, but is there a way to hide the detailTextLabel but still have text there?

Comment: try with [cell.detailTextLabel setHidden:YES] or changing its alpha to 0

Answer (score 0):

In the `commitEditingStyle:` method, inside the

```
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
{
// type in

NSString * cellText;

cellText = [NSString stringWithFormat:[@"%@",cell.textLabel.text]];
//this is going to store the cell's text in a NSString, you can do the same with an array, //just change it from an NSString to an array, or whatever you want to store the value.
}
```

This will set the text to the NSString as soon as the cell is deleted. The code for deciding which cell was deleted isnt here, you need to deal with the `indexPath` for that!